# After updating gradle, an error occurs during compilation of the project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I updated gradle to my project, but after updating during compilation a compilation error started to come out.

I upgraded from version
Android Gradle Plugin version 3.4.1
Gradle version 5.1.1
up to version
Android Gradle Plugin version 3.5.0
Gradle version 5.4.1

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.ui.base.BaseDataViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray_very_light"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="@{viewmodel.errorVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/empty_state_margin_top"
            android:contentDescription="@string/no_internet_alert_details"
            app:srcCompat="@{viewmodel.errorDrawable}"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_error_network" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_46sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_46sdp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.errorTitle}"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
            tools:text="@string/detalization_availability_warning" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_76sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_76sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.errorSubTitle}"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
            android:visibility="@{viewmodel.errorSubTitle.length() &gt; 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            tools:text="@string/no_internet_alert_details" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_76sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_76sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="@{v -> viewmodel.onErrorButtonClicked()}"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.errorButtonTitle}"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            android:visibility="@{viewmodel.errorButtonTitle.length() &gt; 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:strokeWidth="0dp"
            tools:text="авторизоваться" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Here is the error log

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding error(s):

[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method length() in class java.lang.Object","file":"C:\\Users\\User\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Example\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\include_empty_state.xml","pos":[{"line0":58,"col0":30,"line1":58,"col1":61}]}

    at android.databinding.tool.processing.Scope.assertNoError(Scope.java:111)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:124)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:147)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$200(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.runContributingProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:627)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1033)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1198)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:230)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:555)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:546)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:177)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1558)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And so here I am connecting this file to other layouts

```
<include
                        android:id="@+id/empty_state"
                        layout="@layout/include_empty_state"
                        app:viewmodel="@{(com.example.ui.base.BaseDataViewModel) viewmodel}"
                        tools:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Same error, any luck or found any google issue?

Comment: @sam_k I did not find any solution.